# Conditionally separate() using the pipe

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr

Consider some multilingual dictionary data like this:

```
df <- structure(list(tra = c("1. authority, responsibility, dominion / autorité, responsabilité, pouvoir", "2. ability / capacité", "half, part, some / moitié, partie d'un tout", "do, make, operate, execute / faire, opérer, exécuter", "do (etc.) f.o.b. / faire (etc.) pour soi", "1. manière de réveiller. 2. manière de redonner la vie à un mort", "1. qui peut réveiller. 2. qui est capable de redonner la vie à un mort", "A. manière de respirer / respiration. B. vie", "A. manière de respirer / respiration. B. vie", "A. respirer. B. réveiller. C. être libre"), language = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Afar", "Kabiye" ), class = "factor"), metalanguage = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("en/fr", "fr"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("tra", "language", "metalanguage"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The `tra` field sometimes contains English and French translations separated by `/`, sometimes only French, as recorded in the `metalanguage` field. Here's what I want to accomplish:

- keep the `tra` column intact and add two additional columns `tra_fr` and `tra_en`
- if `metalanguage == "en/fr", use`separate()`to split translation in to`tra_en`and`tra_fr`
- if `metalanguage == "fr", fill`tra_fr`with`tra`
- do all this as part of a larger sequence of piped dplyr verbs.

I first went for `separate(tra,c("tra_en","tra_fr"), " / ", remove=F)`, but then
 I discovered the "/" is also used in some of the French-only translations (yay for inconsistent data). So I need some way to apply `separate()` and `mutate()` verbs conditionally based on the `metalanguage` field. How can I do this in the pipe?

(I've studied several prior questions on using conditionals and if_else() with piped dplyr verbs, but so far I have not succeeded in applying what's described for mutate() to separate().)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `group_by %>% do`, and for each group, check the `metalanguage` and *separate* correspondingly:

```
df %>% group_by(metalanguage) %>% do({
    if(.$metalanguage[1] == "en/fr") 
        separate(., tra, c("tra_en", "tra_fr"), " / ", remove=FALSE) 
    else 
        mutate(., tra_fr = tra)
}) %>% as.data.frame()

#                                                                          tra                                 tra_en
#1  1. authority, responsibility, dominion / autorité, responsabilité, pouvoir 1. authority, responsibility, dominion
#2                                                       2. ability / capacité                             2. ability
#3                                 half, part, some / moitié, partie d'un tout                       half, part, some
#4                        do, make, operate, execute / faire, opérer, exécuter             do, make, operate, execute
#5                                    do (etc.) f.o.b. / faire (etc.) pour soi                       do (etc.) f.o.b.
#6            1. manière de réveiller. 2. manière de redonner la vie à un mort                                   <NA>
#7      1. qui peut réveiller. 2. qui est capable de redonner la vie à un mort                                   <NA>
#8                                A. manière de respirer / respiration. B. vie                                   <NA>
#9                                A. manière de respirer / respiration. B. vie                                   <NA>
#10                                   A. respirer. B. réveiller. C. être libre                                   <NA>
#                                                                   tra_fr language metalanguage
#1                                       autorité, responsabilité, pouvoir     Afar        en/fr
#2                                                                capacité     Afar        en/fr
#3                                                moitié, partie d'un tout     Afar        en/fr
#4                                                 faire, opérer, exécuter     Afar        en/fr
#5                                                   faire (etc.) pour soi     Afar        en/fr
#6        1. manière de réveiller. 2. manière de redonner la vie à un mort   Kabiye           fr
#7  1. qui peut réveiller. 2. qui est capable de redonner la vie à un mort   Kabiye           fr
#8                            A. manière de respirer / respiration. B. vie   Kabiye           fr
#9                            A. manière de respirer / respiration. B. vie   Kabiye           fr
#10                               A. respirer. B. réveiller. C. être libre   Kabiye           fr
```

Comment: Works. Adding `en` as a third factor value in `metalanguage` and adding an additional condition with `else if(.$metalanguage[1] == "en")
    mutate(., tra_en = tra)`
also works

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `base R`

```
i1 <- grepl("[/]", df$metalanguage)
df[c('tra_en', 'tra_fr')] <- NA
df[i1, c('tra_en', 'tra_fr')] <- read.csv(text=sub("[/]", ";", 
        df$tra[i1]), sep=";", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df[!i1, 'tra_fr'] <- df[!i1, 'tra']
as.data.frame(df)
                                                                          #tra language metalanguage                                  tra_en
#1  1. authority, responsibility, dominion / autorité, responsabilité, pouvoir     Afar        en/fr 1. authority, responsibility, dominion 
#2                                                       2. ability / capacité     Afar        en/fr                             2. ability 
#3                                 half, part, some / moitié, partie d'un tout     Afar        en/fr                       half, part, some 
#4                        do, make, operate, execute / faire, opérer, exécuter     Afar        en/fr             do, make, operate, execute 
#5                                    do (etc.) f.o.b. / faire (etc.) pour soi     Afar        en/fr                       do (etc.) f.o.b. 
#6            1. manière de réveiller. 2. manière de redonner la vie à un mort   Kabiye           fr                                    <NA>
#7      1. qui peut réveiller. 2. qui est capable de redonner la vie à un mort   Kabiye           fr                                    <NA>
#8                                A. manière de respirer / respiration. B. vie   Kabiye           fr                                    <NA>
#9                                A. manière de respirer / respiration. B. vie   Kabiye           fr                                    <NA>
#10                                   A. respirer. B. réveiller. C. être libre   Kabiye           fr                                    <NA>
                                                                   #tra_fr
#1                                       autorité, responsabilité, pouvoir
#2                                                                capacité
#3                                                moitié, partie d'un tout
#4                                                 faire, opérer, exécuter
#5                                                   faire (etc.) pour soi
#6        1. manière de réveiller. 2. manière de redonner la vie à un mort
#7  1. qui peut réveiller. 2. qui est capable de redonner la vie à un mort
#8                            A. manière de respirer / respiration. B. vie
#9                            A. manière de respirer / respiration. B. vie
#10                               A. respirer. B. réveiller. C. être libre
```